# How can this recursion program reverse all of the characters

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverseSentence();

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    reverseSentence();

    return 0;
}

void reverseSentence()
{
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if( c != '\n')
    {
        reverseSentence();
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

I know the function can store all of the letter entered by user until the last '\n' character. However, I don't know how the program can print the last character and return to the reverseSentence() until it prints out the first letter. Can anyone help explain it step by step?

Comment: It's *really* time you read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please consider entering **ab**. Follow the function through and think about when the **a** will be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of reversing characters of an array. This is my code, to reverse a string, I hope it helps answering your question.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()

{
  char string[]="Reverse String";
  char new[20];
  int count=0;
  int i,j;
  i=0;
  j=strlen(string)-1;

 while(string[count]!='\0')
  {
    new[i]=string[j];
    i++;
    j--;
    count++;
  }
 printf("%s\n",new);

  for(i=0;i<strlen(string);i++)
   {
    printf("%c",new[i]);
   } 
}
```